# Fetching value from webtable and write in excel sheet one by one of each row in a loop

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

1) I am trying to read the values from the webtable of an appliation and write it into the excel sheet one by one.

2) There are 4 values in each row of the webtable that need to be written to excel sheet, but there are some images in each row that i'm ignoring bu using below code.

```html
text.length()>2
```

.

3) There will be 200-300 rows in webtable that need to be fetched and written to excel sheet.

This is the code i have tried. But i dont know how to write it into each row of the excel sheet one by one. Please help me in this regard.

```html
        //get the table
  WebElement statusTable = browser.findElement(By.id("projectstatus"));
  
  //Get all the rows in the table
  List<WebElement> allRows = statusTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
  
  //Get the size(row no) of allRows
  int rowSize = allRows.size();
  System.out.println(rowSize);
 
  
  for (WebElement row : allRows) {
   
   //Get all cell values in each row
   List<WebElement> allCells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
   //System.out.println(allCells.size());
   
   if(allCells.size() > 1){
    for (WebElement cell : allCells) {
     
     
     String text = cell.getText();
     if(text.length()>2){
      
      String value = cell.getText();
      
     }     
    }
   }
   

  // locate the test xl file    
  File file = new File("e:\\Testing_emi.xls");    
  // create input stream    
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);    
  // create workbook    
  HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);    
  // get sheet    
  HSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");    
  // get rows    
  
  
     
   
   HSSFRow row = sheet1.getRow(1);    
   
   
     
  HSSFCell cellEx = row.getCell(0);    
   if (cellEx == null) {    
    cellEx = row.createCell(0);    
   }    
   cellEx.setCellValue(value);
```

Comment: To start with, all of your code where you're trying to write the value to the spreadsheet should be inside your for loop.

Comment: Could you please explain further after moving the excel write code inside for loop what should be done next.. Because there are four(4) values which has to be written inside the each row (4 Cells) of the excel sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//get the table
    WebElement statusTable = browser.findElement(By.id("projectstatus"));

    //Get all the rows in the table
    List<WebElement> allRows = statusTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    //Get the size(row no) of allRows
    int rowSize = allRows.size();
    System.out.println(rowSize);


    // locate the test xls file             
  File file = new File("e:\\Testing_emi.xls");              
  // create input stream                
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);              
  // create workbook                
  HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);              
  // get sheet              
  HSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");             
  // get rows               


   HSSFRow row;             

    for (int i=0; i<rowSize; i++) 
    {
        WebElement webRow = allRows.get(i);
        //Get all cell values in each row
        List<WebElement> allCells = webRow.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        //System.out.println(allCells.size());

        if(allCells.size() > 1)
        {
            HSSFRow excelRow = sheet1.createRow(i);

            for (int j=0; j<allCells.size(); j++) 
            {
                WebElement webCell = allCells.get(j);
                String text = webCell.getText();
                if(text.length()>2)
                {
                    Cell excelCell = excelRow.createCell();
                    excelCell.setValue(webCell.getText());
                }                   
            }
        }
    }

  sheet1.close();
```

Comment: Thankyou @Shail :) Its working, i'm able to print 4 values in each row, but its being written in random cell's not in the order of 1, 2,3 and 4 cells.

Comment: I have used this code   Cell excelCell = excelRow.createCell(j);
                    excelCell.setcellValue(webCell.getText());
Please let me know how to print the values in 1,2,3 n 4 cells in order

Answer (score 0):

Read the values from the Web Table of an application and write it in to the excel sheet one by one.There are 5 values in each row of the Web Table and that need to written in Excel sheet. Below is the working code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Documents\\Selenium jars\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://cosmocode.io/automation-practice-webtable/");
        WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='countries']/tbody"));
        List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        int rowcount = rows.size();
        FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Documents\\Selenium\\output.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sh = wb.createSheet("First Sheet");
        for (int row = 0; row < rowcount; row++) {
            List<WebElement> columns_inrow = rows.get(row).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            int columns_count = columns_inrow.size();
            System.out.println("Number of cells in Row " + row + " are " + columns_count);
            Row ro = sh.createRow(row);
            for (int column = 0; column < columns_count; column++) {

                String celltext = columns_inrow.get(column).getText();
                System.out.println(
                        "Cell Value of row number " + row + " and column number " + column + " Is " + celltext);
                ro.createCell(column).setCellValue(celltext);
            }
            System.out.println("===========================");

        }
        wb.write(fis);
        wb.close();

    }
```